# Where can I find a list of Microsoft Paradox ODBC driver error codes?

Tags: .net, odbc, paradox

I am currently using a Microsoft ODBC driver to connect a .NET application to a Paradox Database. Periodically I get errors like

```
ERROR [HY000] [Microsoft][ODBC Paradox Driver] Reserved error (-3034); there is no message for this error.
```

I would like to find a list of error codes that can translate -3034 into something that means something. Any ideas where to look?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the error codes are specific to Paradox, rather there is a list of generic ODBC errors which may or may not apply to Paradox connections.

For example, from what I can see, error 3034 means

> You tried to commit or roll back a transaction without first using BeginTrans.

..and fails with Paradox as it may not support transactions.

Errors in the 3xxx range in [this list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb221208.aspx) document the errors you might encounter with ODBC connections.  The list pertains to Jet/DAO connections but I believe the same error codes apply to all connections.